# why are the data values 0 after being grayscaled in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grayscale

I am using hmtl canvas to grayscale an image:

```
 var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw, ch);
  var data= imageData.data

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      var grayscale = data[i]*0.2126 + data[i +1]*0.7152 + data[i +2]*0.0722;
      data[i] = grayscale;
      data[i+1] = grayscale;
      data[i+2] = grayscale;
         }
console.log(data);
```

This works, when I click on the image on a page it will be displayed grayscaled in the canvas. However,
when I do `console.log(data);` I get an array of 0s in the console. This doesn't make any sense? When I do `120` instead of `grayscale` it displays `120`s. SO when I do the math, let's say I have a pixel with RGB (80,50,20), according to my formula it would be RGB would be (54,54,54). So why is the output here all zeros?

Comment: And where's the console.log at ?

Comment: after the for loop, all trys

Comment: If i put in 120 instead of grayscale it gives out 120 in the array

Comment: Does your image have transparent pixels? Canvas represents transparent pixels as `rgba(0,0,0,0)` so your math will result in zero values for transparent pixels.

Comment: yes it does. But like for all? shouldn't there be at least some pixels with different values?

Comment: Yep, non-transparent pixels should produce non-zero `grayscale`. Are you sure you looked through the entire array for non-zero values? Also, but less likely, if your image has semi-transparent black pixels they will also result in zero grayscale: eg `rgba(0,0,0,.25)`. If you post your image I'll take a look :-)

Comment: you are right, there are some values other than zero. ok, i see, then it's the conversion into b64 that doesn't work. So just to be clear, the values stored in the array will be converted to integers? Because based on the grayscale formula some of them can come out as floats, right?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner. Correct. JavaScript will see that it has a float being entered into the Uint8ClampedArray and will round that float to the nearest integer and enter that integer into the array.

Comment: Try flooring the value. grayscale = Math.floor(grayscale).